# BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() doesn't go background

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, backgroundworker, sqlconnection

I have WPF application that works with DB. I have `Connect to DB` button. When user clicks that button I want to show some progress animation while app is trying to connect to DB.
Here's my button and progress animation:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Name="btnLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="btnLogin_Click" Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="btnLoginIcon" Source="pack://application:,,,/Content/Images/Connect_Icon.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="btnLoginText" Text="Connect" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
<mui:ModernProgressRing Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ConnectProgressRing" Width="40" Height="40" Visibility="Hidden" IsActive="True" Style="{StaticResource ThreeBounceProgressRingStyle}" />
```

Here's my code for background work:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWorkConnect);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted);

    ConnectProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void LoginToDB()
{
    string ServerPath = Server.Text;
    string Database = Schema.Text;

    dbStr = "Server=" + ServerPath + ";Database=" + Database + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message != null)
        {
            MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Failure to connect", btn);
        }
    }
}

void bw_DoWorkConnect(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        LoginToDB();
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}

void bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ConnectProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

For some reason when I click Connect button and I have wrong Server and DB my window freezes and I can't do anything until I got error message back. Do you have any ideas why is my `LoginToDB()` doesn't go in background?

Comment: Where is `bw_DoWorkConnect` defined? How is it related to `LoginToDB`?

Comment: Scroll down the code

Comment: Besides BGW being obsolete, you don't execute anything asynchronously. `Dispatcher.Invoke` means "run this on the UI thread". It's the same as writing `LoginToDB` right into the Click event

Comment: What .NET version are you using? You could avoid all this if you used `async/await`

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: @Bryuk then there's no reason to use BGW at all. Why don't you use `async void btnLogin_Click()...){... await conn.OpenAsync(); ...}` ? Anything *after* the `await`, including the `catch` clauses will run in the UI thread so you won't have to use `Invoke` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how `bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted` ties in with everything but WPF has the ability to use the async/await pattern. This allows execution to continue on a different thread and the UI thread gets released so your windows does not freeze/hang. Here is your code refactored to make use of that pattern. Again, I have no idea about `bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted` so I removed it for now.

```
private async Task LoginToDBAsync() // notice the async keyword in the method signature
{
    string ServerPath = Server.Text;
    string Database = Schema.Text;

    dbStr = "Server=" + ServerPath + ";Database=" + Database + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbStr))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync(); // will release the thread back to the WPF app and connection continues on new thread until it completes
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message != null)
        {
            MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Failure to connect", btn);
        }
    }
}

// previous name was async void bw_DoWorkConnect(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // notice the async keyword in the method signature. Because its a WPF event callback it returns void and not Task like the above method
{
    ConnectProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    await LoginToDBAsync(); // await db call

    // ui code to be executed after the previous call completes.
    // the continuation is executed on the UI thread
    ConnectProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

}
```

Comment: Here's new event handler. bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted); If you scroll down the code I have definition of that. It executes code after bw completed work

Comment: @Bryuk there's no reason to use a BGW if you can use `async/await`

Comment: @Bryuk - I updated the code. If you use `async/await` you do not have to use the `Dispatcher` at all unless you are executing multiple long running processes in parallel AND you want to update the UI code from those processes. If its a single process and you do not want the UIt to freeze then this is the way to go.

Comment: @Igor there is absolutely no reason to use the BGW or bw_DoWorkConnect event. In fact, it should be considered a nasty bug to use a Click event to start a BGW event that then uses `async/await` while *already* on a background thread. Most likely, the changed code will fail with a cross-thread access exception

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I could not agree more. I think maybe you misread my previous comment? I merely mean that if you are executing multiple threads in parallel that `Dispatcher` (not BGW) could then still be used to update the UI. The method name above `bw_DoWorkConnect` I left the same, I guess I should change it to `onButtonClick`.

Comment: I've got The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @Bryuk - As `PanagiotisKanavos` mentioned you need to tie directly in to the method using a button click (I assume that is what the event is that you want to trigger the action). Get rid of the back ground worker completely. I updated the method name and signature accordingly above.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I updated the code sample to reflect that the entry is a button click not a back ground worker.

Comment: I've tried you example and my window freezes with this code.

Comment: @Bryuk - are you event names the same in the code and in your XAML?

Comment: @Bryuk - notice that I removed your entire implementation of `btnLogin_Click`. You can build it back up in there but try just the code that I have in your code behind file, you should not have any problems.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help a lot! This is actually works. I will change my code to follow you example. Thanks again

Comment: @Bryuk - glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your asynchronous code invokes a call to the dispatcher thread

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
        LoginToDB();
    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

The dispatcher will use the same thread as the UI and your UI will freeze. You need to remove the Dispatcher.Invoke to allow your code to run asynchronously, although I am guessing you have put that in there because LoginToDB references some UI elements?

```
void bw_DoWorkConnect(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    LoginToDB();
}
```

If you want to update the UI then don't catch the exception in the DoWork event handler and let the RunWorkerCompleted event handler check the Error of the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs to update buttons and show messages, etc.

```
private void LoginToDB()
{
    string ServerPath = Server.Text;
    string Database = Schema.Text;

    dbStr = "Server=" + ServerPath + ";Database=" + Database + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

You don't need Dispatcher.Invoke in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, because that method will execute on the UI thread.

```
void bw_RunWorkerConnectCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(e.Error.Message, "Failure to connect", btn);
        return;
    }

    ConnectProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: How can you access fields without dispatcher? Will not you get 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it wpf' ?

Comment: @Bryuk the dispatcher has nothing to do with fields. It's required to access *UI Controls*. You can access fields from any thread. You can't access a UI control from any thread other than the UI thread. The `Completed` event exists so you *don't* have to use `Invoke` inside `DoWork` event

Comment: Only if your field is a UIElement or something which can only be accessed on the UI thread. You can pass data into the BackgroundWorker by passing an object into the RunWorkerAsync as a parameter. You can then access that data using the DoWorkEventArgs

Comment: This LoginToDB() Method is actually a lot bigger. I do populate all the fields on the form when connection is available. So, it's really complicated to have everything in parameters. Some of dropdowns are cascading

Comment: The correct way to use background worker is to do all of your non-UI related long running process (e.g. DB connection) in the DoWork event handler and then pass results to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler through the event args. Then the RunWorkerCompleted event handler processes all of your UI updates.

Comment: @Bryuk if there are a lot of parameters, bundle them in a parameter object. Trying to access the UI controls from the `Login` method itself is *not* a good design. In fact, accessing controls *at all* isn't good WPF practice - your code should *bind* UI controls to fields

Comment: I accepted answer from Igor, but you answer is helpful too. I will follow your suggestions in future. Thanks. Upvote